# How to pass string argument in string macro in c

Tags: c, macros

Say i have macro with x as string parameter `#define a(x) "this is x"`. And if I call as `a(test)` , string formed should be `"this is test"`.

Comment: `#define a(x) "this is " #x`

Comment: Thanks for reply.but if argument is in between the string say "this is x macro"?

Comment: `#define a(x) "this is " #x " macro"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking forward to create strings from macro argument and so, are looking for `# operator`. Within the replacement part of a function-like macro, the `#` symbol becomes a preprocessing operator that converts tokens into strings. So you need

```
#define a(x) "this is " #x
```

or

```
#define a(x) "this is " #x " in the middle."
```